# Android string utf-8 works in layout but not in java code

Tags: java, android, string, utf-8

In my Android application I have some arabic strings stored in the strings.xml file.
when I use the string from the `layout xml` via:

```
android:text="@string/EMAIL_LABEL
```

It works fine, but when I call it from `java code` like:

```
emailLabel.setText(R.string.EMAIL_LABEL)
```

it shows me only numbers instead

Anyone can advice please?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is it a string of numbers or is it the value of the resource ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode characters not displayed in TextView.setText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext)

Comment: Thank you, it was my bad! I used setText(R.string.TEXT_ID) so it printed the id of the string and not the string value itself, I had to do getString(ID), It's a mistake of a beginner but the fact that I'm not, embarrassing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call first getResources() like this:

```
emailLabel.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.EMAIL_LABEL));
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, setText accepts resource ids too.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)

Comment: The solution worked fine for me, Thank you, it was my bad! I used setText(R.string.TEXT_ID) so it printed the id of the string and not the string value itself, I had to do getString(ID), It's a mistake of a beginner but the fact that I'm not, embarrassing

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
String res = getResource ().getString( R.string.EMAIL_LABEL);

emailLabel.setText(res);
```

Comment: Actually I made a mistake of beginners even I'm not, so it's embarrassing a bit, but thank you very much you saved my life :D

Comment: made a mistake of beginners today, be stronger tomorrow and never ever be shy from asking any questions