# Passing Unicode string through JSON request

Tags: android, json

Mysql data has some text with unicode inside, like \uXXXX . How can i display that unicode properly in textview

using json_encode($var) in PHP, resulting \\uXXXX in JSON output

Now, Textview displayin unicode as \\uXXXX instead of symbol. How can i display it as unicode symbol in textview.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext

Comment: Could you not just use `unicodeString.substr(1, unicodeString.length());`? Or does the string have more than just unicode in it?

Comment: yes its more than one and not in particular position of sting. its para with \\uXXXX in it

Answer (score 0):

Open your php file with notpad++, from Encoding menu select "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" then save your php file.

then send final result like this:

```
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $json;
```

this way your characters will be exactly the way they are and you won't get them like \uXXXX.