# Android: find out if Unicode character is printable

Tags: android, unicode

How can I find out at runtime if a unicode character is printable in Android?

For instance, I have the unicode character `\u2249`, which I display in a textview, but it shows as an empty string.

I would like to test whether I can display it, and if I can't, swap it with an alternate value.

Comment: check this links.. hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext

Comment: The Unicode character support isn't complete. Use an iconic font or find an alternative character in place of \u2249. Or use a png.