# Android encoding a string and display in textView

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I have an array of strings which are in latin and have some letters which are turned into "?", I need them to display correctly.

```
String[] asd= {"Srećni nikad ne razmišljaju o sreći."};
```

in "asd" I have strings which I need to display correctly in TextView on my android device, but every "ć", "š" turns into "?".

```
textView.setText(asd[0]);
```

I am using Android Studio. Thanks

Comment: This is supposed to work. Android is unicode so this means č š ž ć đ should work normally. Have you tried setting it from you XML?

Comment: Dont know why, but it doesnt work...How do I do that in xml? thanks

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: Yeah that worked, I changed the way I was doing things to xml resource and then pulling data from there. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio there is two options for encoding you need to check

1- your project encoding 
2- your IDE encoding 
you will find them under setting 
[image]

Please make sure also not to hard code any strings you have to put them in string xml files

Answer (score 0):

Try using Unicode, here is a table for your convenience ;
http://unicode-table.com/en/#00E8

And chech this question, it may help;

[Unicode characters not displayed in TextView.setText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext)

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to put strings like that into your XML and get them from there. It's a good idea too, since that allows you to have several languages, yet using the same code. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)