# Android studio how to save characters č,ć,đ,ž in string?

Tags: android, string, encoding, character-encoding

Generally, I'm trying to save some text from edittext in android studio to string and than later write it to pdf using pdf stamper and send it via e-mail. I'm using default encoding UTF-8 because I cannot (or don't know) to change it since it's hard-coded. User will eventually enter some of these characters. What is the best way to make this characters visible or to prevent user from typing those characters?

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode characters not displayed in TextView.setText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext)

Answer (score 0):

Use special characters and set it to text view like how u set & :- &

or use Html within TextView :-

```
#For example (< Android Nougat):
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#269;"));


#For example (>= Android Nougat):    
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#269;", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

Comment: So you suggest that I, if my edittext is declared as ts, write i.e.
ts.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#269;", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)); for character č, and do this for all other characters I have problem with?

Comment: yes that should work.. or in strings.xml add &#269; and use it in ur view

Answer (score 0):

try this,

`myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#269;"));`

Comment: why myTextView? I enter some text via app in editText box and I want to save that text to string?

Comment: then you can simply  enter your text into text box then store it in string variable.. then show it in toast this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to xml as

```
<string name="random">" č,ć,đ,ž"</string>
```

and you it later by string name