# How can I show Diameter Symbol in a textview? I used the diameter symbol (⌀) (Unicode character U+2300) but it does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used this Unicode character U+2300. But its not reflection in Android Textview. I have used it in both xml layout and in java class.

Comment: how did you use that character, and what was the result?

Comment: You may find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4522563/2641380

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko its showing same as U+2300. But it should show it as diameter symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String str = "\u2300";
textView.setText(str);
```

Comment: Just blurting out code without explanation is not what Stack Overflow is about. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

> Encodings of **Unicode Character 'DIAMETER SIGN'**

```
HTML Entity (decimal)               &#8960;

HTML Entity (hex)                   &#x2300;

How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +2300

UTF-8 (hex)                         0xE2 0x8C 0x80 (e28c80)

UTF-8 (binary)                      11100010:10001100:10000000

UTF-16 (hex)                        0x2300 (2300)

UTF-16 (decimal)                    8,960

UTF-32 (hex)                        0x00002300 (2300)

UTF-32 (decimal)                    8,960

C/C++/Java source code              "\u2300"

Python source code                  u"\u2300"
```

In Android, you can not use this Unicode directly in your text view tag, but first you have to store the string value in your string.xml file and then use it from there

**EX.**

```
<string name="save">SAVE \u2300</string>

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/btnSave"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/save"/>
```

**Output** 
:

[image]

Comment: when the `strings.xml` is saved in UTF-8 encoding, it should even work with the literal symbol; notice the tiny indicator in Android Studio; at the bottom of the editor window.